# display textbox based on dropdownlist selection on modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I need to display a textbox based on the selection of a dropdownlist

I have the following but it is not doing anything:

```
<div id="booking-customer-details-dialog" class="modal fade" tabindex=-1 role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <div class="modal-title h2"><?php _e( 'Edit booking details', 'booking' ) ?></div>
        </div>
        <form ng-hide=loading style="z-index: 1050">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="booking-appointment-status"><?php _e( 'Status', 'booking' ) ?></label>
                    <select class="booking-custom-field form-control" id="booking-appointment-status">
                        <option value="<?php echo CustomerAppointment::STATUS_PENDING ?>"><?php echo esc_html( CustomerAppointment::statusToString( CustomerAppointment::STATUS_PENDING ) ) ?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo CustomerAppointment::STATUS_APPROVED ?>"><?php echo esc_html( CustomerAppointment::statusToString( CustomerAppointment::STATUS_APPROVED ) ) ?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo CustomerAppointment::STATUS_CANCELLED ?>"><?php echo esc_html( CustomerAppointment::statusToString( CustomerAppointment::STATUS_CANCELLED ) ) ?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo CustomerAppointment::STATUS_REJECTED ?>"><?php echo esc_html( CustomerAppointment::statusToString( CustomerAppointment::STATUS_REJECTED ) ) ?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 'Test' ?>"><?php echo esc_html(Test ) ?></option>
                        <?php if ( Config::waitingListActive() ) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo CustomerAppointment::STATUS_WAITLISTED ?>"><?php echo esc_html( CustomerAppointment::statusToString( CustomerAppointment::STATUS_WAITLISTED ) ) ?></option>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    </select>
```

The above is on a modal. The below is my Javascript that I use for the IF statement to determine if the Cancelled option is selected

```
<SCRIPT>

var s = document.getElementById('booking-appointment-status');
var booking-appointment-status = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;

if (booking-appointment-status == 'cancelled') {
              <div class="checkbox">
              <label><br>
              <input id="booking-delete-notify" type="text"       
    checked="true" style="display:none;"><br>
                    Reason</label>
              </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="display: block;"             id="booking-delete-reason-cover">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="booking-      delete-reason" placeholder="Cancellation reason">
            </div>
}
    else if (booking-appointment-status ==      'CustomerAppointment::STATUS_CANCELLED') {
<div class="checkbox">
              <label><br>
              <input id="booking-delete-notify" type="text"       
    checked="true" style="display:none;"><br>
                    Reason</label>
              </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="display: block;"             id="booking-delete-reason-cover">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="booking-      delete-reason" placeholder="Cancellation reason">
            </div>
}

</SCRIPT>
```

Please assist me. I have been struggling with this for a while
Separately they are working i.e I see the dropdown and I can display the textbox permanently

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjqZd.jpg)

Comment: plz show the expected output

Comment: There is a link to: How it should look